# Synchronize with then/catch method of ES6 Promises in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, promise, es6-promise

I have a angular controller I need to test. This controller calls a service to retrieve data from a server. The service returns ES6 Promises.

```
function MyController($scope, MyService) {
  $scope.doSomething = function () {
    MyService.foo().then() {
      whatever...;
    };
  };
};
```

In my Jasmine test, I mock the service which returns Promises too:

```
var resolve;
var reject;
createPromise = function () {
 return new Promise(function (_resolve, _reject) {
    resolve = _resolve;
    reject = _reject;
  });
};

var myServiceMock = {
  doSomething: jasmine.createSpy('doSomething').and.callFake(createPromise)    
};

beforeEach(module('someApp', function ($provide) {
  $provide.value('MyService', myServiceMock);
}));
```

And I manually call the global resolve (or reject) with or without a parameter to check on my controller.

```
it('shall call the service', function () {
  $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  controller = $controller('MyService', { $scope: $scope });
  controller.doSomething();
  myService.resolve();
  expect(whatever...);
});
```

The problem is that the resolve call is asynchronous. So I am testing my expected outcome while the then function is being run.

Instead of returning Promises, I tried to return simple custom object that would turn resolve as a synchronous call but it turns out Promises have some specific rules that would be too cumbersome to reimplement in a mock (like when you have then.().catch().then patterns for example).

Is there a way to test this kind of thing in a easy and sychronous way in Jasmine ?

Comment: Just don't try to make promises synchronous. Embracy asynchrony even within your test suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell Jasmine that your test is asynchronous and it should wait for it to complete before deciding that it's failed. You do this by adding a `done` parameter to your spec declaration (`it` call), and calling `done` at the end of your expectations:

```
it('shall call the service', function (done) {
  $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  controller = $controller('MyService', { $scope: $scope });
  var promise = 
    controller.doSomething()
      .then(function() {
         expect(whatever...);
         done();
      });

  myService.resolve();
});
```

An easier way to make your mocks resolve automatically is to use the `Promise.resolve` method:

```
doSomething: jasmine.createSpy('doSomething').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve())
```

You then don't need to call `myService.resolve` - the mock automatically returns a resolved promise.

I've recently started using the [jasmine-promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-promises) module which makes writing the promise call even easier - and ensures that if the promise rejects, the error and call stack are reported, for easier debugging. With `jasmine-promises` this would just become:

```
it('shall call the service', function () {
  $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  controller = $controller('MyService', { $scope: $scope });

  return controller.doSomething()
      .then(function() {
         expect(whatever...);
      });
});
```